# Crystal Report - Print Records at Specified Location on Page

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have a crystal report that is used to print pay slips for roughly 500 employees.
Three pay slips are listed on each page and each pay slip is separated by a horizontal line which is used to determine where the pay slip should be cut in order to separate them for hand out to employees.

I would like each pay slip to be printed at a specified location on each page. I would like the first pay slip to be printed at a set location at all times and the second at a set location below the first and the third at a set location below the second so when all 170 pages are printed and stack together they can be easily cut apart on a guillotine

I am using crystal report xi

Comment: is it a pre-printed stationary

Comment: No it is not, the pay slips are printed on blank letter size pages

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put a long text box as divider at the left side of the report.